# It will be or it will have been

Tags: tense, future-time, future-perfect

Please tell me what the difference between the following sentences is

1. Tomorrow it will be ten years since we moved in.
2. Tomorrow it will have been ten years since we moved in.

Thank you.

Comment: The perfect isn't really necessary, so 1 is fine with 2 overly-cumbersome.

Comment: The future perfect has its place; it adds a future-retrospective nuance that is not present in "will be", which simply looks forward.

Comment: _Tomorrow it will have been ten years since we moved in_ is present perfect tense. English does not have a future tense.

Answer (score 9):

There is little difference in *meaning*.  There is a slight difference in *perspective*.

> Tomorrow it will be ten years since we were married.

This sentence has a slightly *forward-looking* perspective, as if I'm thinking about the future with my wife.

> Tomorrow it will have been ten years since we were married.

Again, similar meaning, but the use of the perfect has a slightly *backward-looking* perspective, as if I'm considering all that time we spent together.

Neither is more *correct* than the other, and neither is in any way *negative* (unless I say it in a way that seems sarcastic or disparaging).  These are just two ways to say the same thing but with a subtle difference in nuance.