# By the time we get there, he will be/will have been gone

Tags: difference, future-tense, perfect-aspect

> By the time we get there, **he will be/will have been** gone.

I would like to know whether there is a difference between these two or the perfect tense is wrong here.

I assume that with the perfect tense, more emphasis is placed on the fact that he has been dead for a while.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/115938/it-will-be-or-it-will-have-been).

Answer (score 1):

We use the **Future Perfect** to make predictions about actions which we expect to be completed before a particular time in the future:

> I'll have finished this assignment by Friday.
>
> When I finish this book, it means I'll have read all of her books.
>
> He'll have had the operation by July and should be a lot fitter then.

We usually use a time adverb/phrase (e.g. soon, by then, within the next week etc.) with this kind of prediction. The times can be very close to "now".

So, *by the time we get there, he'll have been gone* is perfectly correct. You use the time phrase "**by** the time we get there", and you point out that something will have happened by the time you arrive. It makes even more sense if there is more information/context (e.g. By the time we get there, he'll have been gone *for 3 hours*).

I feel that "he'll have been gone" is more correct than "he'll be gone" in this particular context. But I'd use the **Future Simple** with some other time clause, *not "by"*. For example, *When we get there, he'll be gone*.